# Javafx - What is the proper way of adding items to an Observable List that's in a different class folder from another class folder

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

i have two different project (Project A and Project B) Project A and B has a List View. When items are been added to project A List View (Observable List) the same items will also be added to Project B List View (Observable List). 
So i made Project B Observable List `public static` then added Project B to Project A Libraries and assign Project A Observable List to Project B Observable List.

**My Question Is**
this a proper way of doing this, making Project B Observable List `static`

Comment: whatever the problem, using static fields is not the solution ;) You need to implement api for sharing the state, f.i. bind the content of the list in B to the content of the list in A .. Anyway, not much help possible without a mcve, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4):

Your question is missing essential details, but giving enough "insight" to clearly state: you are going down the wrong rabbit hole.

When you have two "projects" that are somehow "connected"; then you should clearly design your whole solution to express that.

In your case, the solution could be to define a **third** project C that contains the common parts, and then ensure that projects A and B can make use of it. Making something **static** is most likely the absolute wrong answer. In real world projects, you are extremely cautious about using  *static* in the first place (it leads to direct coupling of classes, and easily gets into your way when doing unit testing). But using it as remedy like that ... that is like putting dirty duct tape on a flesh wound (it works, when you got nothing else, but nothing else).

Long story short: you are trying to *fix* a symptom (using bad means), instead of identifying the root cause, and resolving that.

Comment: yes i did that too.Project C would act as a bridge between Project A and B. the thing is that when an instance of Project C `ProjectC c=new ProjectC` is call by A and B.  it creates a new reference of the class

Comment: You use new with Java class names. A project is not a class. You probably want to edit your question to give more details about your setup.